# table is not visible in the window. How to fix it?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

```
String[] columnNames = {"Customer ID", "Name", "Address", "Salary"};
dtm = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0); // 0 is row count
customerDetailsTbl = new JTable(dtm);
JScrollPane tablePane = new JScrollPane(customerDetailsTbl);
tablePane.setBounds(customerDetailsTbl.getBounds());
add(tablePane);
```

this is the code that I used to create table. but it does not visible in the window.

[screenshot of the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoZ23.png)

I tried many ways to solve this but didn't get any result. Can you guys help me with this

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can better understand your problem and provide a solution that is better suitable for your case.
Note: to make changes in layout visible to the user you should call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the container of your scroll pane.

Comment: It will do you no favours to use null layouts. So, [avoid null layouts in Swing](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/114-avoid-null-layouts-in-swing)

Comment: Even if a null layout was a good approach (it’s not), `tablePane.setBounds(customerDetailsTbl.getBounds());` would be wrong.  Each component’s bounds are relative to its parent.